# Table column's auto_increment flag not preserved by backup?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

After dumping a database on MySQL-5.1.73 and loading it into MySQL-5.5, I notice, that at least one table's primary key didn't have its `auto_increment` flag transferred... The `describe table` on the original reads thus:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FIELD_ID  | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| ID        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ISSUE_ID  | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| LOCK_HASH | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| LOCK_TIME | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RANK      | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| TYPE      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But, after loading into the target, the last column is empty -- `auto_increment` flag of the `ID`-field is gone.

Indeed, looking into the dump, I see the table's definition as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "AO_60DB71_LEXORANK" (
  "FIELD_ID" bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "ID" bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  "ISSUE_ID" bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "LOCK_HASH" varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "LOCK_TIME" bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  "RANK" varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  "TYPE" int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
  KEY "index_ao_60db71_lexorank_rank" ("RANK"),
  KEY "index_ao_60db71_lex604083109" ("ISSUE_ID"),
  KEY "index_ao_60db71_lex1632828616" ("LOCK_HASH")
);
```

There is no obvious instruction to set ID to automatically increment... The non-default flags used with `mysqldump` were:

```
extended-insert=false
compatible=postgres
single-transaction
```

Is this a known problem? Should I attempt a bug-report with MySQL (Oracle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is a MySQL-only option (other Database software uses different commands -- for example, PostgreSQL uses a special column type called `SERIAL`).

Therefore, when you export with `--compatible=postgres` it will not be included in the dump.

You can either stop exporting with the PostgreSQL compatibility flag, or you can manually add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option.  In either case, if you actually plan to import this schema into PostgreSQL, you will have to modify the dump file to change the column type to `SERIAL` for any column that you want to auto increment.

---

Note that, despite the name, the `--compatible` option **does not** transform the schema into a form that is guaranteed to work in the database you chose.

All that the option does is *remove* things that are unique to MySQL so that you can more easily finish the transformation yourself, either by hand or using some kind of script that you have built.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible):

> This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers. It only enables those SQL mode values that are currently available for making dump output more compatible. For example, `--compatible=oracle` does not map data types to Oracle types or use Oracle comment syntax.

Comment: In general, Mikhail should check the command he is using for making the dump.

Comment: Should not `mysqldump` automatically do the necessary changes, if compatibility with PostgreSQL is requested? Or, at least, warn me about the problem?

Comment: @MikhailT. No. See my update to the answer.